# Asynchronous execution of Stored Procedure in EXT

Tags: c#, extjs

I have a stored procedure to export an Excel file which runs from a [Direct Method] by clicking a button.

But if data is very large can take up to 20 minutes to execute, how I can run it in parallel and keep using the program while stored procedure is running?

Comment: You can [increase timeout in ExtJS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.data.Connection.html#cfg-timeout) and [use async controllers on your server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Do you need to get the result back?

Comment: If you don't need to use the data returned from this procedure, you may want to create an interface to run this procedure and return an "OK" status to ExtJS just to make sure the command was received and executed.

Comment: When the procedure is done it exports the results to an Excel file. I was thinking if opening and calling the procedure from a new page would work. But I dont know how I can do it... working on it